# Pass values from a component to Redux Store

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am learning Redux with React.I have a Form in a component.I would like to pass data from that component to actions of Redux. I am using below code for submitting that Form.

```
handleSubmit = event => {
    var mouse = 'mouse';
    this.props.dispatch(mouse);
  }
```

My action is like below

```
const authActions = (value) => {
    return {
        type: 'Hello',
        payload: value
    };
}

export default authActions;
```

My Reducer is like below

```
 import authActions from '../actions/authActions';

    const initialState = {
        user: {},
        error: {}
    }

    const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'Hello': {
                console.log(action.payload);
            }
            default: return state;
        }
    }

    export default reducer;
```

May be I could not express myself properly. I don't know whether I am in a right way of learning Redux or not. Please help me anyone.

How can I send data from my component to action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you'd be using `mapActionsToProps` wrap `authActions` in `dispatch` and add it to your props, but if you have the redux `dispatch` method in your props as you appear to here you should be able to simply do

```
handleSubmit = event => {
  var mouse = 'mouse';
  this.props.dispatch(authActions(mouse));
}
```

`authActions` is an action creator. You call it with your value and get an action back. You then dispatch the action to the redux store.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is a great help for me. Thank You.